# save screenshot in parse server

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm trying to make my android App take a screenshot for the current running activity and then save it in parse server .. but it didn't work ... does anyone knows what's wrong with this code

my code ...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                takeScreenshot();


            }
        });

    }
    private void takeScreenshot() {
        Date now = new Date();
        android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);

        try {
                           String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + now + ".png";

            // create bitmap screen capture
            View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

            File imageFile = new File(mPath);

            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            int quality = 100;
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, quality, outputStream);



            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
            byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();

            // Create the ParseFile
            ParseFile file = new ParseFile(uri.toString(), image);
            // Upload the image into Parse Cloud
            file.saveInBackground();

            // Create a New Class called "ImageUpload" in Parse
            ParseObject imgupload = new ParseObject("Image");

            // Create a column named "ImageName" and set the string

            // Create a column named "ImageFile" and insert the image
            imgupload.put("IMG", file);

            // Create the class and the columns
            imgupload.saveInBackground();

            // Show a simple toast message
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image Uploaded",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // Several error may come out with file handling or OOM
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post the logcat with the error, or i'll just ask you "what have you tried? did you step it with a debugger perhaps?"

Comment: it tells me that the image is uploaded .... but nothing appears in parse

Answer (score 1):

You should change your code to

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, quality, outputStream);
outputStream.flush();// before file usage
outputStream.close();
```

And remove flush from end of method.

Answer (score 0):

Parse Work on Thread so first get call back to ParseImage is save or not that take call back response like...

```
    final ParseFile file = new ParseFile(uri.toString(), image);
    // Upload the image into Parse Cloud
    file.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {

        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (e == null) {
                // success
               // hear save image
              // upload image into parse
                uploadImgae(file);
            } else {
                // fail
            }
        }
    });
```

then this method.

```
public void uploadImgae(ParseFile file) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // Create a New Class called "ImageUpload" in
    // Parse
    ParseObject imgupload = new ParseObject("Image");

    // image
    imgupload.put("IMG", file);

    // Create the class and the columns
    imgupload.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {

        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (e == null) {
                // success
            } else {
                // fail
            }
        }
    });
}
```